# Create an android app for my site

Tags: android, asp.net, upload, server

I have a website (written in aspx) that allows me to upload and download files like google drive.
If I would like to create an android app that does the same, would I need to implement a new server that my android app will use?

I read little about web services which allow sharing code between apps. Should I use it?

Comment: Yes you can use webservices to communicate to your existing server via android app

Comment: So this is the standard solution? Or there is a better solution?

Comment: You do not necessarily need to implement a new server. You can add services such as [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) to existing web sites.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and effective option other than re-creating an app for Android devices, would be to use CSS to actually fit the site onto mobile screens. All you need to do is create an new css file with something like the following:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {

}
```

The above would change the layout of the site for screens having a width of 320px. Inside the tag you would need to then enter the desired changes you would like.

That way you will be making the site available to Windows, Android and iOS users.

Hope this helps :)